# free web database for small android app

Tags: android, database, node.js, sockets

I'm creating an app where user A marks locations on google maps ,those location are stored in a sqlite database on the phone. Now I would like to be able to send those markers to another user where they open up on their map in the app. Now I was just wondering what I would need. I don't want code I just want kind of a checklist. I want this to be free because I have no money right now to rent a server. If I could even use my laptop as a local host just for testing purposes and expand it to a real server later would be ok. A friend said I could use socket.io and node.js and if that's true I will but I need a server / server db to handle everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out [Amazon SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/pricing/):

> You can get started with Amazon SimpleDB for free. New and existing
>   customers receive 25 SimpleDB Machine Hours and 1 GB of Storage for
>   free each month. Many applications should be able to operate
>   perpetually within these free tier limits.